# Vertically align text from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a table that has long headers. I'm trying to rotate the text so that it runs from the bottom of the cell to the top. I've tried a combination of writing-mode: vertical-rl; and transform: rotate(-180deg);.

The best I can seem to come up with is adding a translateY(-100%) to the transform property. That manages to line up the text the way I'd like it to the bottom of the table cell, but now I can't figure out how to move the whole thing back down to align properly.

Here's the page I'm working on. Scroll down to see the table.

I've been pulling my hair out all afternoon. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

http://www.1000islandsplayhouse.com/patron-members-club-new/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added `transform-origin: center center;`in your css. I hope this is what you need.

```css
td span{
  border:1px solid;
  height:200px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg); 
 }

td {border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1">
<tbody class="row-hover">
<tr class="row-1 odd">
 <td class="column-1"></td><td class="column-2"><span>Tickets Included</span></td><td class="column-3"><span>Best Seats</span></td><td class="column-4"><span>Parking at the Firehall Theatre</span></td><td class="column-5"><span>Tax Receipt Over Ticket Value</span></td><td class="column-6"><span>Repeat Visits</span></td><td class="column-7"><span>Voting Rights at the AGM</span></td><td class="column-8"><span>Playbill Listing</span></td><td class="column-9"><span>Page to Stage Events</span></td><td class="column-10"><span>Discounted Patron Rates for Additional Tickets</span></td><td class="column-11"><span>Complimentary Beverage on Opening Night</span></td><td class="column-12"><span>Front of the Line Access</span></td><td class="column-13"><span>Brochure Listing</span></td><td class="column-14"><span>Parking at the Springer Theatre</span></td><td class="column-15"><span>Invitation to First Day of Rehearsals</span></td><td class="column-16"><span>Monthly 'Insider's Group'</span></td><td class="column-17"><span>End of Season Dinner</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-2 even">
 <td class="column-1">Visionary<br>
($10,000+)</td><td class="column-2">30</td><td class="column-3">•</td><td class="column-4">•</td><td class="column-5">•</td><td class="column-6">•</td><td class="column-7">•</td><td class="column-8">•</td><td class="column-9">•</td><td class="column-10">•</td><td class="column-11">•</td><td class="column-12">•</td><td class="column-13">•</td><td class="column-14">•</td><td class="column-15">•</td><td class="column-16">•</td><td class="column-17">•</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-3 odd">
 <td class="column-1">Champion<br>
($4,000-9,995)</td><td class="column-2">20</td><td class="column-3">•</td><td class="column-4">•</td><td class="column-5">•</td><td class="column-6">•</td><td class="column-7">•</td><td class="column-8">•</td><td class="column-9">•</td><td class="column-10">•</td><td class="column-11">•</td><td class="column-12">•</td><td class="column-13">•</td><td class="column-14">•</td><td class="column-15">•</td><td class="column-16">•</td><td class="column-17">•</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-4 even">
 <td class="column-1">Guardian<br>
($1,400-3,995)</td><td class="column-2">16</td><td class="column-3">•</td><td class="column-4">•</td><td class="column-5">•</td><td class="column-6">•</td><td class="column-7">•</td><td class="column-8">•</td><td class="column-9">•</td><td class="column-10">•</td><td class="column-11">•</td><td class="column-12">•</td><td class="column-13">•</td><td class="column-14">•</td><td class="column-15">•</td><td class="column-16">•</td><td class="column-17"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-5 odd">
 <td class="column-1">Benefactor<br>
($690-1,399)</td><td class="column-2">10</td><td class="column-3">•</td><td class="column-4">•</td><td class="column-5">•</td><td class="column-6">•</td><td class="column-7">•</td><td class="column-8">•</td><td class="column-9">•</td><td class="column-10">•</td><td class="column-11">•</td><td class="column-12">•</td><td class="column-13">•</td><td class="column-14"></td><td class="column-15"></td><td class="column-16"></td><td class="column-17"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-6 even">
 <td class="column-1">Partner<br>
($490-685)</td><td class="column-2">7</td><td class="column-3">•</td><td class="column-4">•</td><td class="column-5">•</td><td class="column-6">•</td><td class="column-7">•</td><td class="column-8">•</td><td class="column-9">•</td><td class="column-10">•</td><td class="column-11"></td><td class="column-12"></td><td class="column-13"></td><td class="column-14"></td><td class="column-15"></td><td class="column-16"></td><td class="column-17"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-7 odd">
 <td class="column-1">Supporter<br>
($390-485)</td><td class="column-2">5</td><td class="column-3">•</td><td class="column-4">•</td><td class="column-5">•</td><td class="column-6">•</td><td class="column-7">•</td><td class="column-8">•</td><td class="column-9">•</td><td class="column-10">•</td><td class="column-11"></td><td class="column-12"></td><td class="column-13"></td><td class="column-14"></td><td class="column-15"></td><td class="column-16"></td><td class="column-17"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! This is fantastic. I wasn't able to wrap my head around how to make it work. Thank you for your help :) :)